How to ignore compile errors in Typescript/Electron for unreachable code
I'm rather new in Typescript/Electron and try to make a text based game.
I started from the equivalent of a hello world electron application and start implementing some core logic with classes/interfaces that reference classes I simply haven't implemented yet.
My code looks something like this (Player doesn't reference any other classes)
import { app, BrowserWindow } from 'electron';
import { Player } from './Character/Player';
export default class Main {
    static mainWindow: Electron.BrowserWindow;
    static application: Electron.App;
    static main() {
        Main.application = app;
        Main.application.whenReady().then(() => {
            Main.mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ width: 800, height: 600 });
            Main.mainWindow.loadFile('../html/index.html');
            let p : Player = new Player('Hero');
            p.callName();
            //Game.start();
        })
    }
}
Main.main();

and run it with
npm run start
and get errors like
src/ts/Interfaces/Character.ts:16:9 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Shape'.
Now I want to test sections of my code, having commented out all calls and imports to other classes but I still get compile errors.
I tried adding  "allowUnreachableCode": true, to my tsconfig.json
I also tried running npm with npm run start || true
How can I make the application execute and ignore unreachable (un-compileable) code without having to bring them in a compilable state first or comment out everything?

No, compiling the whole project is required by design.
If you do like "use-before-implement" (like TDD), you can write a declaration file to avoid compilation errors.
declare const Shape: any // or specify a type if you've already designed its type


Sounds like Typescript doesn't keep full track of references. So if I get this right a declaration file basically just provides an api that acts like a dummy implementation.
That means I can postbone the implementation, but I still need all classes to be compile-able.

@MenP Do you mean that you actually wrote the implementation, but TS didn't realize it?

no I meant. If I understand declaration files correctly, then a declaration file only satisfies calls to non existent references.
I could declare a class like 'Weapon' and instantiate in my main function and it would compile without an implementation.
However once I start implementing 'Weapon' it would have to immediately satisfy the declaration and compile (aka can't have bad code lying around).
